# possessive の with a verb

Tags: verbs, particle-の, possession

I was having a discussion with someone over the sentence

私**の**作った絵を使った!
(He) used the drawing I made

I have never seen the possessive の being used as NOUN + の + VERB (only N+の+N) so I insisted the sentence should be written as

私**が**作った絵を使った

Who is correct here? Is the "NOUN + possessive の + VERB" construction a valid one to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I will be able to clarify this to you.

The の between 私 and 作った絵 makes perfect sense if you look at the verb as you would look at a modifier/adjective.

Few examples:

買った本 - book that was bought
書いた手紙 - letter that was written
走っている子供 - child that is running

Even though, you're using a verb, it acts and modifies the noun as an adjective, that's why you can treat it as a noun phrase.

Hopefully you got it by now. If you need some more help, let me know :)

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Is using が here also possible?

Comment: I wish I could give you a solid yes/no answer here, but I cannot. To me it looks weird with が and it [b]might[/b] incorrect gramatically.